# How to unregister all ProgressBars?

Tags: python, dask

The [dask documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html#progress-bar) explains that a ProgressBar can be unregistered by calling `pbar.unregister()`, where `pbar` is the respective ProgressBar instance.

However, this method only works, if the user has access to that ProgressBar instance. Using IPython I was in a situation where I've lost that reference.

Is there a way to find all instances of globally registered ProgressBar objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
dask.set_options(callbacks=set())
```